# fullCalendar.js call viewRenderer

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the viewRender in fullCalendar.js to do some custom processing of my calendar events. Just for info, this is so that in the view I can potter off to the server to request the events that are contained within the view, and just return those events, the data returned is then processed on the client and added as an array eventSource.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar(
{
  viewRender: function (view, element)
  {
    var data = {};
    data.periodStart = view.intervalStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    data.periodEnd = view.intervalEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

    call.myServer(data,function(replyData)
    {
      // some custom code 
    });
  }
}
```

This was working very well, for me until I needed to update the events in the current view. I can't seem to find a way of getting the calendar to "refresh" the current view that also calls the viewRender function.

According to the docs docs here http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/

> This callback will get triggered when the user changes the view, or
>   when any of the date [navigation methods](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/) are called.

So I tried:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment("something sensible"));
```

And on [sangram parmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1660178/sangram-parmar)'s suggestion

```
use $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

But the viewRender never gets called.

I could duplicate / abstract my viewRender logic into a separate function and call that, pushing the new events into the calendar, but that seems a little unclean.

Is there anyway to programmatically call viewRender or to force a refresh of the current view?

Comment: use   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');

Comment: Thanks Sangram, this unfortunately still didn't call the viewRenderer

Comment: It looks as though fullCalendar doesn't refresh the current view as it thinks nothing has changed. Switching the view to something else works (but is a bit poo - it is a solution as my calendar is only ever month... but yak)       $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicWeek');                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');